# Matplotlib adjust canvas size to content / remove white space Python

Tags: python, canvas, matplotlib

Is there a way to make Matplotlib automatically adjust the canvas size to the plotted content?

This example illustrates the issue:

```
fig = plt.figure(frameon=False, tight_layout=True)
ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])
ax.axis('off')
plt.text(0.1,0.1,"foobar")
plt.savefig("bla.png", dpi=300, bbox_inches="tight")
```

and I get stuff like that:

[image: blank canvas]

I would like to get rid of all the white space, so just have the plotted text.
I already tried every `tight_layout` command and likewise I found, but nothing had an impact on the size of the canvas.

I know it is dependent on the parameters passed at `fig.add_axes`, but I didn't find a way to get the size of the plotted text in advance to add the axes with the according sizes.

Comment: In my opinion, the easiest way to achieve something like this is to crop the resulting file using `ImageMagick` or similar tools.

Comment: `tight_layout` knows about the axes which is what it is bounding to (`ax.axis('off')` doesn't _remove_ the axis, it just makes them invisible.  There was a PR to make `tight_layout` ignore invisible artists, but I don't recall if it got merged or not.